# Access to sheets by name while adressing the fg.sheet file by URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm in a situation where I need to send data to  specific tabs(sheet) in a google sheet file (basically it's a G.Sheet file with one sheet that is a "template").
two cases: a/ the needed sheet exists then just append the data in that one, if not then use a specific sheet (template) copy it to create the new sheet as a new tab and append in it the data sent.
Each new sheet get its name as a parameter in the flow of data to be appended.
I'm really confused and know where to start and hope I'm clear enough.
So far I have this little code (not including the copying of the template cuz I don't know how to do it).

```
// pseudo is the name of the sheet in the file

function doGet(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/IDXXX/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.pseudo); 
  
  addData(e,sheet);
}
 
function doPost(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/IDXXX/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.pseudo); 
  
  addData(e,sheet);
}
 
 
function addData(e,sheet) {
  //some data to append in the e.pseudo sheet
var id = e.parameter.id ;
var date = e.parameter.date ;
var textRef = e.parameter.textRef ;
var niveau = e.parameter.niveau ;
var cycle = e.parameter.cycle ;
var vitesse = e.parameter.vitesse ;
var reference = e.parameter.reference ;
sheet.appendRow([id,date,textRef,niveau,cycle,vitesse,reference]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought `e.psuedo` should have been `e.parameter.psuedo`

Comment: you are right. Noticed it after posting. appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this sample code on how to create a new sheet from a template sheet. Assuming your sheet name can be obtained in `e.pseudo` or in `e.parameter.psuedo` as what @Cooper advised.

```
// pseudo is the name of the sheet in the file

function doGet(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/IDXXX/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.pseudo); 
  
  // Sheet doesn't exit, create new sheet from a template
  if (sheet == null) {
    // Select "template" sheet and copy to the current Spreadsheet
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName("template").copyTo(ss);
    // Rename the copied template sheet
    sheet.setName(e.pseudo);
  }
  
  addData(e,sheet);
}
```

### What it does?

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) will return `null` if the sheet name doesn't exist. Select your `template` sheet and use [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) to create a copy in your destination spreadsheet.
- rename the newly copied sheet based on your input sheet name using [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename)

### Note:

- just replace the name of your template sheet

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update the answer accordingly. I would appreciate it if you could also provide a sample sheet

Comment: First of all Thank you so much. it did solve my problem of having a copy from th e template that take the name carried by the pseudo. I didn't get back to you cuz I'm trying to figure out why,  while the new tab is created, it doesn't receive the data I'm sending.  I think that I'm wrong as reg the ID of the file and the sheets. I started with the ID of the file when I had only one sheet then moved in situations with mutilple sheets therefore a huge messs I'm doing. do you think it's because after having copied from the template I should make the copy "active" ? Hope it make sense.

Comment: You mean that when a new sheet was created using the template sheet, the data was not added? have you verified if the content of your event object `e` is not empty? You don't need to make the copied sheet active since you already passed it's sheet object when you used `copyTo()`.

Comment: Oups I thought that it's because I'm addressing the "wrong" tab/sheet". Now when I send data to an existing sheet it works fine. When i send it to an non-existing one it creates the copy (thx to your help) however doesn't capture the data sent. Is that because of the timining and may be I need to pause for some time before asking to consider the received data ?